# Извлечение emoji из картинки в строку на python

Tags: python, emoji

Есть такое изображение с Emoji[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их извлечь и поместить в строку?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1. распознать изображённые предметы. 2. подобрать подходящие по смыслу символы из нужного вам алфавита пиктограмм. 3. profit.

Answer (score 0):

Окей, гугл, [opencv template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html).
Когда научишься находить заранее известный эмодзи в изображении, делаешь базу эмодзи в искомом приложении и пробуешь находить их по очереди.
Процесс можно будет ускорить, создав дерево - например, ищешь желтые кружки, если такой нашёлся с определённой степенью уверенности, только тогда ищешь желтые лица. Но это уже подробности.

Answer (score 0):

Используем [вот это](https://www.tensorflow.org/?hl=ru). Тренируем на каждое эмодзи. Поскольку они одинаковы, одного прогона по всем эмодзи в количестве одной штуки хватит.

P. S. Вот несколько советов по оптимизации:

1. То, что сказал автор выше (тренировка на ключевые объекты (жёлтый круг, мартышка), после вторым кругом в анализатор обычных эмодзи, с людьми, мартышек, котов)
2. Использование многопотока и подключение интегрированной графики (самое то для нейросетей, которые работают с изображениями)